# how to send bolean value to database in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

this how i send in postman and it works

```
{
    "isAdmin": true,
    "type": "shoes",
    "description": "true"
}
```

this how i send in vue

```
 async onAddCategory() {
     
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("type", this.type);
    data.append("isAdmin", this.isAdmin);
      data.append("description", this.description);
      const response = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:4000/api/categories", data, 
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
```

this is my console which shows  "isAdmin": true,

```
{
    "_id": "640f4e785d1e1c8d7c1be439",
    "isAdmin": true,
    "name": "t",
    "email": "t@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$O1hMb2Tc7mdK7iD4gbZ/VeV1htualyj0Fry86pt6stv7boIk.0ft2",
    "__v": 0
}
```

i keep getting unauthorize because isAdmin = true doesn't go through

Comment: 1. Could you please share the postman output?
2. In Vue, You are not even sending isAdmin: true as you are doing in postman.       data.append("isAdmin", this.isAdmin);

Comment: Postman works....change the code it still showing unauthorized

Comment: what are the object key-values received on the backend?  what criteria does the backend use to send back unauthorized?  please post the code for the endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
   var data = {
        isAdmin: this.isAdmin,
        description: this.description,
        type: this.type
      };
```

instead of data.append